# Equation of the envelope surface

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the family of planes in three dimensions that intersect the positive x, y, and z axes at point A, B, and C, respectively, such that the tetrahedron whose vertices are these three points and the origin, O, has a ﬁxed volume V . Find the equation of the envelope surface deﬁned by this family of planes.

I can't even imagine the planes, hence can't determine the family of planes. Maybe someone can show me the picture of planes and the equation of the family of planes?

Comment: The same picture one-dimension down should help you imagine what is happening.  Alternatively, imagine you are doing some carpentry and sanding a corner.  Algebraically it is easy to write down the family.

Comment: So the equation for the family of planes will be $\frac{x}{A}+\frac{y}{B}+\frac{z}{C}=1$? What does the volume has to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the plane so defined is $\dfrac{x}{A}+\dfrac{y}{B}+\dfrac{z}{C}=1$ Here is a drawing of it:

[image]

It shows the four points taken as vertices of a tetrahedron. From elementary formulas its volume is $V=ABC/6$. As stated in the problem's wording, this volume has to be constant for all the planes into the family, so one among $A,B,C$ is determined by the other two. Let it be $C$: $C=\dfrac{6V}{AB}$

We have three equations to find the equation of the envelope (by eliminating $A$ and $B$)

$$\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
    \dfrac{x}{A}+\dfrac{y}{B}+\dfrac{ABz}{6V}=1 \\
    \dfrac{\partial}{\partial A}\left(\dfrac{x}{A}+\dfrac{y}{B}+\dfrac{ABz}{6V}-1\right)=0 \\
    \dfrac{\partial}{\partial B}\left(\dfrac{x}{A}+\dfrac{y}{B}+\dfrac{ABz}{6V}-1\right)=0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right.$$